# What programming language is FogBugz written in?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, fogbugz

From what I've read it appears that FogBugz was originally written in VBScript. Now apparently they use their own custom compiler and language that will translate the source code to more "accessible" languages such as PHP and (I think) C#. Is there a name for this language? What does a hello world look like in it? Is there any hope of seeing this compiler released to the public?

Comment: @Kevin, I felt this was too programming related to go there, and if it should go there then it should go to the (dead) fogbugz stackexchange

Comment: @KevinDTimm - FogBugz != StackOverflow

Comment: @APC - et.al.  Holy cow am I a dummy - Sorry, mea culpa, my mistake, won't happen again, etc., etc., etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wasabi, not public, probably not :-)

Comment: Maybe someone who works on FogBugz can give us a hello world? :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FogBugz#Wasabi , http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/09/01b.html , http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/09/01.html

Comment: "Wasabi, a very advanced, functional-programming dialect of Basic with closures and lambdas and Rails-like active records " Am I the only person that laughs a little bit inside when reading this? Functional? Basic? I really must see this language

Comment: -1 for "not public, probably not".  The compiler and FogBugz source is available to all download customers (not on-demand).

Comment: Here's Jeff Atwoods take on Wasabi. I guess Joel and Jeff have made up since then... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/09/has-joel-spolsky-jumped-the-shark.html

Comment: "Even in a world filled with 3 gigahertz $200 dual-core CPUs" We have that now don't we? lol.

Comment: @Sam, I wasn't aware of this ... can this be cited anywhere?

Comment: @Joel Martinez, I don't know of any public posts, but I have both the compiler and the full FogBugz source on my local computer where I have FogBugz installed for plugin development.  I can post a screen shot if you need proof.  :-)

Comment: Reading about a functional dialect of VBScript just makes me think of that snarky old comment that any significantly advanced language will end up having a broken subset of LISP (or favorite language X) in it.

Answer (score 4):

FogBugz is written in a combination of Wasabi and C#.

Wasabi is a custom language based on VBScript that originally was compiled to VBScript, PHP, and JavaScript.  It's still used in FogBugz but the outputs are only C# and JavaScript.  The Wasabi compiler is included with a purchase of FogBugz as is all of the Wasabi source code.  If you know VBScript it's easy enough to learn the differences.

C# is used for all plugins (actually any .NET language should work).  Some new features are written as plugins, like workflow and custom fields.